# Google Maps JavaScript API v3 25,000 Usage Limits

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does the 25,000 per day map load usage limit on the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 apply to the API key or the website using it?

Here is a scenario: A developer, who has an API key, creates multiple websites for multiple clients, each with its own domain name. These websites may be shared on a single server (same IP). The code that calls the Maps API runs on the client side (in the browser). Do these sites share the 25,000 limit or each of them get its own 25,000?

Here is the Google page on usage limits (it does not make this distinction):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

Edit: The Google Maps API Community Support page refers users to StackOverflow for questions regarding usage. I haven't gotten any answers here yet. Does anyone know how to contact Google and ask them this question? I couldn't find any way to contact them about this.

Answer (score 1):

The usage quota is applied on the per project basis.

The limit of 25K daily map loads is shared between all API keys that belong to the same project. So, if you have only one API key in your project and use it on multiple domains, all these domains will share the 25K quota.

Regarding the last question, you can reach out to Google Maps API support team and ask questions only if you have a Premium plan license. Otherwise you are stick to community support.

https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/support#contact-support

Hope this solves your doubt.

#### Update

As of 2019 Google introduced a Google Maps Platform and deprecated Premium and Standard plans. In Google Maps Platform there is no daily quota by default, although you can set your own daily limit in your project for each API.

Also you can now file support cases with Google Maps support team from your cloud project interface.

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand usage for map loading, as:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: { lat: 42.345, lng: 12.46 }
        });
```

I searched on [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload) and found this:

> How are map loads applied against the usage limits for Google Maps APIs for Web? A single map load is charged when [..] A web page or application displays a map using the Google Maps JavaScript API.

So, in your case, if you use your API key to load different maps on multiple websites, it will result to a unique 25,000 limit of request per day